# Finding average of column of data in R

Tags: r, rscript

I am working with data about assassination attempts. I have to find the average baseline Polity score of countries whose leaders survive versus
those who do not.

The data set looks like:

```
"year","country","leadername","age","politybefore","polityafter","interwarbefore","interwarafter","civilwarbefore","civilwarafter","result"

1929,"Afghanistan","Habibullah Ghazi",39,-6,-6,0,0,1,0,"not wounded"
```

I think what I have to do is create two subsets of data, one of successful attempts and one of unsuccessful attempts, and then find the avg of the `"politybefore"` column, but I don't know the most efficient way to do that.

The options for result are:

```
levels(leaders$result)
 [1] "dies between a day and a week"              
 [2] "dies between a week and a month"            
 [3] "dies within a day after the attack"         
 [4] "dies, timing unknown"                       
 [5] "hospitalization but no permanent disability"
 [6] "not wounded"                                
 [7] "plot stopped"                               
 [8] "survives but wounded severely"              
 [9] "survives, whether wounded unknown"          
 [10] "wounded lightly"
```

So anything resulting in death is a success.

Comment: How can you calculate **successful attempts and one of unsuccessful attempts**? Please provide more information in your question.

Comment: It is not necessary to manually split the data set, there are functions in R that allow you to apply a function to a subset defined by grouping, in this case "result". `dplyr` is one such method, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530428/dplyr-mean-of-a-group-count, if you need further help, provide minimum  data http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve